# Where to place and how to find mustache templates in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, mustache

I'm trying to understand where to store my mustache templates for a java servlet web application and how to tell the servlet where the template is located. How do I set the file path, etc?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{ 
  MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory(); 
  Mustache fromFile = mf.compile("template.mustache"); 
  Example e = new Example(); e.variable = "this is some value!";
  fromFile.execute(response.getWriter(), e); 
}
```

This is my code. My template is located in the same folder as my servlet file.

Answer (score 2):

```
mf.compile(new InputStreamReader(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("template.mustache")), "template.mustache");
```

should do what you need. I think you may also be able to do the easier

```
mf.compile("template.mustache");
```

but, I'm not entirely sure.

The template file should be in the same folder as your compiled .class files.

Comment: juhu, exactly what I needed :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use [Trimou Mustache implementation](http://trimou.org) and it's built-in [ServletContextTemplateLocator](http://trimou.org/doc/1.2.1.Final/trimou-doc.html#_servletcontexttemplatelocator) (or feel free to implement your own TemplateLocator :-).

Comment: It seems a really nice Mustache implementation. I've did some benchmark tests and it is pretty close to spullara's version (without its optimizations). But it is far more extensible, which a very attractive point. The only thing that bothers me was its dependency tree, too fat. My project took only 8Mb, including it made my deployment package 3Mb bigger.

Comment: Just FYI - the footprint of Trimou 2.0 was greatly reduced, see also https://github.com/trimou/trimou/releases

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I'll take a look into the new version.